# Connecting end points of a line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I have this line. You can't see the rest of the line in the picture but It's only one line and I want to connect the two ends to close it and convert it into a polygon. I don't know how to connect it. I'm using QGIS 3.10

[image]

Comment: You can also use `Snap Geometries to Layer` tool if there are many of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Vertex tool` from the toolbar to move the vertex of the line to connect it to the other vertex. Click on Toggle editing and the vertex tool will be enabled.

[image]

Make sure to enable snapping in order to close the line correctly.

Comment: Follow up with *Vector > Geometry Tools > Lines to Polygons.*

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may prefer to *add* a new line between the endpoints, as opposed to pinching them together.  In this case, start editing the line layer and add a new line segment by utilizing the **Add Line Feature** button.

After saving the edit, the line layer displays as a loop, although it is not yet a polygon.  It will also have an additional feature in its attribute table (for a total of two), due to the new line.  You must reduce the number of line features to one, via the *Vector > Geoprocessing > Dissolve* tool.

Convert the dissolved line loop to a polygon with the *Vector > Geometry Tools > Line to Polygons* tool.  Voila! you now have a polygon layer with a single attribute record.